# Formatting SQLite Python Result

Tags: python, database, sqlite, simulation

For a text basketball simulation game, I am using an SQLite database to store players and teams. I am coding the game in Python and ran into a problem. When I’m coding the jump ball, I am trying to print out a simple text saying who is jumping. The code is as follows.

```
Print(f“{PlayerDB.get_players_by_position(connection, 5, 1)} and {PlayerDB.get_players_by_position(connection, 5, 2)}} will jump.”)
```

The result is:

```
[(‘Player’, ‘One’)] and [(‘Player’, ‘Two’)] will jump.
```

My definitions for the functions are on the PlayerDB file and they select the first and last name of the player where the position and team id = a specific #.

I want to print it out so that the brackets, parenthesis and quotation marks are not there. How can I go about to do this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
print(f“{PlayerDB.get_players_by_position(connection, 5, 1)[0][0]} {PlayerDB.get_players_by_position(connection, 5, 1)[0][1]} and {PlayerDB.get_players_by_position(connection, 5, 2)[0][0] PlayerDB.get_players_by_position(connection, 5, 2)[0][1]}} will jump.”)
```

Comment: When I try this, the result only gives the last name and nit the first and last. 
The result is: One and Two will square off for the Jump

Comment: I made some changes, please try again

Comment: IT WORKS! THANK YOU!